# Opencv to identify and process numbers on windows screen (google meet), How can I use it?

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, tesseract, video-processing

Would like to know the possibility of using Python and `OpenCV` to identify the numbers that are appearing on my screen (fixed position) in a meet meeting, I would like to be able to use them to save their performance in real time in Excel, as well as create alerts for me, for example, `X = 3m/s`; `y = 2m/s`, save the update of these numbers (the update occurs every 2 seconds) in addition to receiving an alert if X becomes greater than 4m/s. Sorry for the question.

I haven't tested it yet, I'm in the process of looking for videos on YouTube about it, but most of them only work by taking a screenshot of the screen and then analyzing it, or using a recorded video or webcam.

EXEMPLE OF THE PRINTSCREEN: [example of a screen on which you would like to operate and know the digits

[image: (control screen on the right)]

Are locked in these respective positions:
-Action screen on the left -person performing a workout
-Control screen on the left, with 5 or more variables, the value of the variables changes and updates every second
--I would first like to be able to identify these variables and digits using Python, for example `V1(t=1) = 119`; `V2(t=1) = 5`; `V3(t=1) = 2.3`; `V4(t=1) = 0. V5(t=1) = 0`. I would save these numbers in an Excel table with the value of these variables and a time or counter in another column.

The second part would be to analyze these numbers in real time, for example, let's say variable 1 cannot exceed 140, when its value reaches 140, put a warning on the screen, or noise, or some way of identifying this.

I haven't tried anything yet, just watching YouTube videos trying to find something similar or an example of use, I found videos talking about `opencv` and `tesseract`.

Comment: You're on the right track, try out some online tutorials for opencv and pytesseract. If something does not work out, come back with a programming question with code + example + desired results